# How templates works when consumed by another module

Tags: c++, templates, generics

When creating, for instance, a generic linked list (denote it by `List<T>`), I was always told that if I use somewhere a `List<int>` and elsewhere a `List<short>` then actually the compiler would generate two different implementations of `List`, one using `int` and another using `short`. That makes sense to me and kind of reminds how [SGLIB](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/) works in C.

But I don't understand how the process works when using different compiled modules. I mean, if I make a library with a `List<T>`, which code is generated, given that it's impossible to know how the code will be consumed? The code for a `List<char>` would certainly compile very differently from the code of `List<int>`, so what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: Template libraries are usually not compiled but shipped as header only. This is one of the largest drawbacks of templates and is planned to be addressed in the next standard with a module system.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't fully understand it yet. A generic List, in this case, would have the *implementation* inside a header file?

Comment: @JohnSmith templates **always** have their implementation inside a header file. It's a classic beginner mistake to try to separate the template definition from the implementation. Have a look at a standard library header that comes with your compiler.

Comment: Ha I see. That makes perfect sense! Just out of curiosity, do you known or have any reference on how this 'problem' is planned to be solved? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3347.pdf there are more resources including a presentation at the clang developer Meeting, but you will find those yourself. It is important to stick with basic C++ as a beginner. Most of the standardization stuff isn't going to be particularly enlightening.

Comment: And in case it's not distributed as a self-containing header, but the implementation is separated, then it depends on the compiler how to handle it. VC++ many years ago generated several variations for the possible future types of the template functions. This could really blow up compilation time and memory.